# How to copy vector column-wise?

Tags: c++, vector

I've a 2d vector say

```
vector < vector < int > > sample;

sample = 1 2 3 4 5
         6 7 8 9 0
         1 1 1 1 1
         2 2 2 2 2
```

Now I want to copy only the last two columns into another 2d vector like

```
vector < vector < int > > test;

test = 4 5
       9 0 
       1 1
       2 2
```

How can I do this efficiently ?

Comment: The problem is that your memory is laid out like this: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2]. If you're looking for something to be as fast as memcpy here you'll be out of luck unless there's some funky SIMD instruction you can use. More than likely, there's nothing much faster than a good ole' for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
#include <algorithm>

vector<vector<int> > new_vector;
new_vector.resize(sample.size());

for (size_t i = 0; i < new_vector.size(); ++i) {
    new_vector[i].resize(2);
    copy(sample[i].end() - 2, sample[i].end(), new_vector[i].begin());
}
```

Comment: your's is what i want but I'm getting segmentation fault in runtime.

Comment: I forgot one line when I entered it first. Do you have the new_vector[i].resize(2); line?

Answer (score 3):

I heard boost has a foreach loop

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > v;
BOOST_FOREACH(std::vector<int> const &i, test) {
  v.push_back(std::vector<int>(i.end() - 2, i.end()));
}
```

If you haven't boost at hands, I would go with a usual for loop. But I don't think I would use nested  `std::vector` in the first place. If you only ever have two-column rows, best use a vector of `boost::array<int, 2>`.